# How to access a div using some other div's class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have 5 divs in which first four divs have same class but 5th div have some other class. Now, how can I access any of the first four divs using the class name which is present in 5th div which is named "otherclass" in my case? We cannot give any id to any div, have to use the class name only

```
<div class="sameclass">
    <p>first div</p>
</div>

<div class="sameclass">
    <p>second div</p>
</div>

<div class="sameclass">
    <p>third div</p>
</div>

<div class="sameclass">
    <p>fourth div</p>
</div>

<div class="otherclass">
    <p>fifth div</p>
</div>
```

Comment: add one extra common class in all five div.

Comment: You can do something like `$('.otherclass').prevAll('.sameclass').last().text()` But i dont understand your requirement. Why not just tag the first div if that is what you want like .`$('.sameclass:eq(0)')`

Comment: You want to access the DIVs on a specific event or generally?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set the class id also same if yes then its not possible to step forward.

You are only allowed to use an ID name once per page. Repeating ID names is not allowed. Unless you're using it as an internal anchor or a Javascript hook, you're possibly better off changing it from ID to class, rather than changing the name for the second one and then redefining everything in the CSS.

Comment: no, i am not using any id. i have to access using classname only